# UnPublishAsync vs Unpublish in SessionAwareCoreServiceClient

Tags: publishing, workflow

We are using `Unpublish` method in Workflow to unpublish items, but got exception from Database:

```
> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
> "EDA_ITEMS.READ_ITEM". ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current
> operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOCK", line 205 ORA-06512: at
> "TCMDBUSER.EDA_ITEMS", line 1163 ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire
> with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired ORA-06512: at
> "TCMDBUSER.EDA_ITEMS", line 1343 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Once we changed to use method `UnPublishAsync` the issue is gone. Can anyone explain what happens under the hood?

Comment: From the ORA errors present in your log it appears that there are a few threads operating on the database and conflicting with one-another. These could be transactions that your code spins up, it could be other CM transactions, or perhaps the Workflow module is locking some items while they are in the workflow.

Have you tried running your unpublish code without workflow, i.e. as a standalone Core Service client to see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: Remarkable! The Stack Trace for the error will provide more insight where the database lock occurs. Are you using a TransactionScope in the workflow code?

Comment: We don't use TransactionScope

Comment: outside of workflow, it works fine